# get pixel value from canvas image, CORS restriction

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, cors

so obviously this is quite a problem with some browsers, because I googled a number of hits regarding the "canvas gets tainted" mumbo jumbo when you try and get pixel data from canvas images, like :

var pix = context.getImageData(3200,3200,1,1).data;

So far I already tried the crossorigin = '' and XMLHttpRequest, but I still get the same problem. Then again, I don't know if I'm implementing it wrong and just being a noob. I will greatly appreciate it if someone could please help me with this problem. Struggling with it 1.5 days, before turning to a forum question as last resort. Note that my code works for Firefox browsers, but not for Chrome... It his crucial that my implementation has cross-browser functionality. This is a small javascript code snipped I extracted from my main project to isolate, and try and fix, the problem:

```
<html>
<head>
  </head>
    <body>
      <canvas id="myCanvas" width="6029" height="6968"></canvas>
      <script>  <!-- Javascript section-->

      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'); //get canvas from html code via identity

      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');    //get context of canvas
      var imageObj = new Image();       //create image object 
      imageObj.src = 'gauteng.png'; //define the image of the image object


      imageObj.onload = function()  //trigger function after the image has loaded in image object
      {
        try
        {
          context.drawImage(imageObj,0,0);  //draw the image object onto context of canvas

          var imgd = context.getImageData(3200,3200,1,1);   //get pixel at x coord 3200, and y coord 3200
          var pix = imgd.data;  //get the RGB values from pixel

          // print out RGB values with alert            
          alert('R val= '+pix[0].toString()+ "\r\nG val= "+pix[1].toString()+"\r\nB val= "+pix[2].toString());

        }
        catch(err)  //display error message if exception is thrown
        {
          alert(err.toString());
        }
     };

     </script>  
  </body>
</html>
```

I can also include my approach for the XMLHttpRequest:

```
imageObj.onload = function() {

    try
    {
        var inputFile = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        inputFile.open('get', 'gauteng.png', true); //open example file

        inputFile.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(inputFile.readyState==4) //document is ready to parse
            {
                context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);

                //pixel location from image
                var imgd = context.getImageData(3200,3200,6029,6968);
                var pix = imgd.data;

                alert(pix[0].toString()+ " "+pix[1].toString()+" "+pix[2].toString());
            }
        }

        inputFile.send(null); //close file after finished

    }
    catch(err){ alert(err.toString());}
  };
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are firing the xmlhttprequest to load the image when the loaded event from the image get's fired, which doesn't really make sense, because you want the xmlhttprequest to be sent if loading of the image fails as far as i understand your problem. And if the loading fails the onload function should not get triggered. You could try to use the .onerror event handler instead of .onload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when it is cross origin and you are working with canvas many issues are resolved by this:

```
imageObj.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';   
// crossOrigin attribute has to be set before setting src.
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hey Aameer, thanks for the reply, and thank you for pointing out that it should be before the src. Eventually this worked for me after a few tests. Initially I tried running this from the files before uploading it to the domain...and it did not work. Only after uploading the new file to the domain, and running it from there, did it work. (We learn something new every day, although frustrating). Ok but cool Aameer, thanks again.