# SecurityError: The operation is insecure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, canvas

I am creating an AngularJS application which has a canvas where the user can upload a picture. I am using

```
scope.image = scope.canvas.toDataURL()
```

to achieve what I want to do, which is to create a BASE64 encoded string out of my image. When the user has finished picking his picture he submits the BASE64 string to the web service which changes it to a .jpg file. Everything is working fine.

But the user has the opportunity to change his image. He can get it from the database into the same canvas and select a different image. The canvas can show the old image but when I want to choose another image I get the following error:

```
SecurityError: The operation is insecure
```

I have tried to add the following line to my code:

```
image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous')
```

which allows me to change the image without the error but then the image from the database is not displayed for some reason that is unknown to me.

Does anybody know of a way to be able to get an image from a server and display it into a canvas and then be able to change it into another image from my computer without getting the SecurityError?

Comment: the other images come from another domain and are treated via cross-domain security restrictions, maybe use/enable [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: You must also [configure your server](http://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get pixel value from canvas image, CORS restriction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26798635/get-pixel-value-from-canvas-image-cors-restriction)